# For people with high body odor, is it better to wear cotton or microfiber?

Tags: physiology, clothing

For people with high body odor, is it better to wear cotton or microfiber? It's a tough question as there is a good argument for both sides.

Argument in favor of cotton:

> As it has lower breathability, it would better absorb the sweat letting less odor through to the atmosphere.

Argument in favor of microfiber:

> As it has higher breathability, it would decrease temperature and thus lower sweat production.

Which would most decrease others' perception of the smell?

Comment: The breathability of microfiber means that (smelly) substances get into the fibres themselves. Also some natural fibres (wool) may have some antibacterial/antifungal properties. See http://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/4690/cycling-clothing-care-products

Comment: Welcome to Skeptics! In order to keep the scope of the site to a manageable size, [we require proof that the claim questioned has proponents](http://meta.skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/864/when-in-doubt-ask-for-a-citation). Please edit your question with a proof of that. A quote or a link will do nicely, but "My friend told me that..." isn't. Answers that do not conform to this will eventually be closed as off-topic.

Comment: It seems to me as this claim is quite notable, as being effective in dealing with body odour is a strong selling point for both, and in particular micro fibre is sold as a more effective replacement for cotton training t-shirts. E.g. See any Decathlon sport store.

Comment: How about the application of deodorant and the use of soap and water.

Comment: This isn't a claim to be debunked, just a difference of opinion. Off-topic.

Comment: Its better to wear high quality deodorant, at least for the person next to you.